# Count rows with SQL

Tags: sql, count, rows

Please, help me with SQL query creation.

I have two tables, companies and users. users table has company_id field.

I need to count how many companies has no users at all.

Any help will be good! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM companies a LEFT JOIN users b
       on a.company_ID = b.company_ID
WHERE b.company_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFIddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd139/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM companies c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM users u
  WHERE u.company_id = c.company_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM companies c LEFT JOIN users u
ON c.company_id = u.company_id
WHERE u.company_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count(tblCompanies.ID)
From tblCompanies
left join tblUsers ON tblCompanies.ID = tblUsers.CompanyID
Where tblUsersID IS Null
Group By tblCompanies.ID
```